# Geopandas: OSM download problem (UrbanAccess)

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, geopandas

Complete beginner here, just crash-coursing the [sample code](https://github.com/UDST/urbanaccess/blob/dev/demo/simple_example.ipynb) of a python package "[UrbanAccess](https://github.com/UDST/urbanaccess)". Everything was going well, except one part where I have to download the OSM: (The geopandas version is 0.12.2.)

> nodes, edges = urbanaccess.osm.load.ua_network_from_bbox(bbox=bbox,
> remove_lcn=True)

Then the error message was:

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py:202: 
UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  super().__setattr__(attr, val)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in crs(self)
    430         try:
--> 431             return self.geometry.crs
    432         except AttributeError:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5574             return self[name]
-> 5575         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5576 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in _get_geometry(self)
    231 
--> 232             raise AttributeError(msg)
    233         return self[self._geometry_column_name]

AttributeError: You are calling a geospatial method on the GeoDataFrame, but the active geometry column ('geometry') is not present. 
There are no existing columns with geometry data type. You can add a geometry column as the active geometry column with df.set_geometry. 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   5599             try:
-> 5600                 existing = getattr(self, name)
   5601                 if isinstance(existing, Index):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5574             return self[name]
-> 5575         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5576 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in crs(self)
    432         except AttributeError:
--> 433             raise AttributeError(
    434                 "The CRS attribute of a GeoDataFrame without an active "

AttributeError: The CRS attribute of a GeoDataFrame without an active geometry column is not defined. Use GeoDataFrame.set_geometry to set the active geometry column.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19732\129358322.py in <module>
----> 1 nodes, edges = ua.osm.load.ua_network_from_bbox(bbox=bbox,
      2                                                 remove_lcn=True)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\urbanaccess\osm\load.py in ua_network_from_bbox(lat_min, lng_min, lat_max, lng_max, bbox, network_type, timeout, memory, max_query_area_size, remove_lcn)
     74     two_way = False
     75 
---> 76     nodes, edges = network_from_bbox(lat_min=lat_min, lng_min=lng_min,
     77                                      lat_max=lat_max, lng_max=lng_max,
     78                                      bbox=bbox, network_type=network_type,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\osmnet\load.py in network_from_bbox(lat_min, lng_min, lat_max, lng_max, bbox, network_type, two_way, timeout, memory, max_query_area_size, custom_osm_filter)
    844         'lat_min, lng_min, lat_max, and lng_max must be floats'
    845 
--> 846     nodes, ways, waynodes = ways_in_bbox(
    847         lat_min=lat_min, lng_min=lng_min, lat_max=lat_max, lng_max=lng_max,
    848         network_type=network_type, timeout=timeout,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\osmnet\load.py in ways_in_bbox(lat_min, lng_min, lat_max, lng_max, network_type, timeout, memory, max_query_area_size, custom_osm_filter)
    648     """
    649     return parse_network_osm_query(
--> 650         osm_net_download(lat_max=lat_max, lat_min=lat_min, lng_min=lng_min,
    651                          lng_max=lng_max, network_type=network_type,
    652                          timeout=timeout, memory=memory,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\osmnet\load.py in osm_net_download(lat_min, lng_min, lat_max, lng_max, network_type, timeout, memory, max_query_area_size, custom_osm_filter)
    135     polygon = Polygon([(lng_max, lat_min), (lng_min, lat_min),
    136                        (lng_min, lat_max), (lng_max, lat_max)])
--> 137     geometry_proj, crs_proj = project_geometry(polygon,
    138                                                crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})
    139 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\osmnet\load.py in project_geometry(geometry, crs, to_latlong)
    443     """
    444     gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
--> 445     gdf.crs = crs
    446     gdf.name = 'geometry to project'
    447     gdf['geometry'] = None

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in __setattr__(self, attr, val)
    200             object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)
    201         else:
--> 202             super().__setattr__(attr, val)
    203 
    204     def _get_geometry(self):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   5614                         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
   5615                     )
-> 5616                 object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   5617 
   5618     @final

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in crs(self, value)
    441         """Sets the value of the crs"""
    442         if self._geometry_column_name not in self:
--> 443             raise ValueError(
    444                 "Assigning CRS to a GeoDataFrame without a geometry column is not "
    445                 "supported. Use GeoDataFrame.set_geometry to set the active "

ValueError: Assigning CRS to a GeoDataFrame without a geometry column is not supported. Use GeoDataFrame.set_geometry to set the active geometry column.
```

My code is exactly same as the sample code, except for the part right before creating the transit network, where I added this one to convert int64 to object. However removing this part seems to not change anything with the error...

> #### #date column conversion from int64 to object
>
> loaded_feeds.calendar_dates=loaded_feeds.calendar_dates.astype({'date':'object'})
>
> loaded_feeds.calendar_dates['date']=loaded_feeds.calendar_dates['date'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
>
> print (loaded_feeds.calendar_dates.dtypes)
>
> loaded_feeds.calendar_dates.head()

To be honest, as someone only have done python 101 in bachelor, I do not think I have any knowledge whatsoever to analyse this error. I I tried to grasp whatever I could try, like removing every code that deviated from the sample code, but in the end it seems to be a problem within the urbanaccess package or geopanda, so I don't really understand what I should do...

Comment: This is an error originating from the underlying functions of the urbanaccess package. Are you sure that you use the exact same library versions as they do in their example? It might be that something has changed in newer library versions and that that is the reason the example breaks.

Comment: Dear Saaru,

It seems to be the issue indeed! Their website (https://udst.github.io/urbanaccess/installation.html) said any version newer than certain version is fine, (>=) but I suppose that statement should be taken with a pinch of salt...

Comment: If you can set a breakpoint `site-packages\osmnet\load.py` at line 444 you can check what is stored in the variable `gdf`. If it indeed is simply missing a geometry column but does have the geometry info in other column(s), you could try patching that code and do what is suggested in the error. It might be that it the only thing you need to fix.